# Can this where in subquery be optimized?

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery

Currently the query takes ~ 0.2 seconds. Is this the best it gets? Because it feels rather slow for the amount of data I have in my database. I've tried creating an inner join out of it but I can't get it to work.

```
SELECT player_id,
(
    SELECT sum(kills)
    FROM lcs_result
    where lcs_result.riot_match_id in (
                                        SELECT lcs_result.riot_match_id 
                                        FROM lcs_result 
                                        WHERE lcs_result.player_id = t.player_id
                                    ) and lcs_result.team_id=t.team_id
) as total_kills_in_team,
(
    SELECT sum(total_gold)
    FROM lcs_result
    where lcs_result.riot_match_id in (
                                        SELECT lcs_result.riot_match_id 
                                        FROM lcs_result 
                                        WHERE lcs_result.player_id = t.player_id
                                    ) and lcs_result.team_id=t.team_id
) as total_gold_in_team
FROM lcs_result as t
group by player_id;
```

Changing it to `EXISTS` doesn't have any impact on performance.

`EXPLAIN`:

```
+----+--------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+-------------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | type  | possible_keys         | key               | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                               |
+----+--------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+-------------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | t          | index | player_id,player_id_2 | player_id         | 5       | NULL | 1340 | NULL                                |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | lcs_result | ref   | lcs_result_ibfk_3     | lcs_result_ibfk_3 | 4       | func |   41 | NULL                                |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | lcs_result | ref   | player_id,player_id_2 | player_id         | 5       | func |    7 | Using where; FirstMatch(lcs_result) |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | lcs_result | ref   | lcs_result_ibfk_3     | lcs_result_ibfk_3 | 4       | func |   41 | NULL                                |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | lcs_result | ref   | player_id,player_id_2 | player_id         | 5       | func |    7 | Using where; FirstMatch(lcs_result) |
+----+--------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+-------------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------+
```

`CREATE`:

```
| lcs_result | CREATE TABLE `lcs_result` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kills` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deaths` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assists` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_gold` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `minions_killed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `match_result` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `region` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_played` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_entered` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `riot_match_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `match_time_seconds` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `player_id` (`player_id`),
  KEY `lcs_result_ibfk_3` (`team_id`),
  KEY `player_id_2` (`player_id`,`role`),
  CONSTRAINT `lcs_result_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`player_id`) REFERENCES `player` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `lcs_result_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`) REFERENCES `team` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1353 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Sample of data in table:

```
+----+-----------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+
| id | player_id | kills | total_gold | riot_match_id | team_id |
+----+-----------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+
|  1 |         1 |     4 |      18403 |          1669 |       1 |
|  2 |         2 |     4 |      16752 |          1669 |       1 |
|  3 |         3 |     3 |      18372 |          1669 |       1 |
|  4 |         4 |     6 |      21601 |          1669 |       1 |
|  5 |         5 |     0 |      13980 |          1669 |       1 |
|  6 |         6 |     1 |      13119 |          1669 |       2 |
|  7 |         7 |     1 |       9006 |          1669 |       2 |
|  8 |         8 |     0 |      10451 |          1669 |       2 |
|  9 |         9 |     4 |      17027 |          1669 |       2 |
| 10 |        10 |     3 |      16244 |          1669 |       2 |
| 11 |         1 |     1 |       6452 |          1670 |       1 |
| 12 |         2 |     0 |       8947 |          1670 |       1 |
| 11 |        13 |     1 |       6099 |          1670 |       1 |
| 12 |        14 |     1 |       8942 |          1670 |       1 |
| 13 |        15 |     0 |       7473 |          1670 |       1 |
+----+-----------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+
```

Sample of expected result:

```
+-----------+---------------------+--------------------+
| player_id | total_kills_in_team | total_gold_in_team |
+-----------+---------------------+--------------------+
|         1 |                 20  |            127021  |
|         2 |                 20  |            127021  |
|         3 |                 17  |            89108   |
|         4 |                 17  |            89108   |
|         5 |                 17  |            89108   |
|         6 |                 9   |            65847   |
|         7 |                 9   |            65847   |
|         8 |                 9   |            65847   |
|         9 |                 9   |            65847   |
|        10 |                 9   |            37913   |
|        13 |                 3   |            37913   |
|        14 |                 3   |            37913   |
|        15 |                 3   |            37913   |        
+-----------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Does every player belong to one team only?

Comment: Yes, they belong to one team only. Problem is that I want the sum of kills of results that they were part of. 5 players per team but not always the same 5 players in a team. Does that make sense?

Comment: No. Do you want the sum of kills per team, per match or per team and match? Better to show some samples rows (say 10) and expected results.

Comment: I'm sorry, a bit hard to explain. The goal is to have the sum of all kills (as well as gold as you can see) ever made by the player plus the entire team (so the player itself + 4 team-mates) grouped per player. The reason why I use `WHERE IN` is because it's not the same group of 5 players for every match. Is that better?

Comment: Ah, I see now. Is the combination `(player_id, team_id, match_id)` unique?

Comment: Yes, those combinations are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is want you want:

For every player, find his team and calculate the sum of kills and golds for all the matches of that team:

```
SELECT 
    p.player_id,
    SUM(t.kills)      AS total_kills_in_team,
    SUM(t.total_gold) AS total_gold_in_team
FROM 
        ( SELECT player_id, team_id, match_id
          FROM lcs_result
          GROUP BY player_id, team_id, match_id
        ) AS p
    JOIN 
        ( SELECT team_id, match_id
                 SUM(kills) AS kills,
                 SUM(total_gold) AS total_gold
          FROM lcs_result
          GROUP BY team_id, match_id
        ) AS t 
      ON  t.team_id = p.team_id
      AND t.match_id = p.match_id
GROUP BY
    p.player_id ;
```

If the combination `(player_id, team_id, match_id)` is unique, then the above is equivalent to:

```
SELECT 
    p.player_id,
    SUM(t.kills)      AS total_kills_in_team,
    SUM(t.total_gold) AS total_gold_in_team
FROM 
        lcs_result AS p
    JOIN 
        lcs_result AS t 
      ON  t.team_id = p.team_id
      AND t.match_id = p.match_id
GROUP BY
    p.player_id ;
```

Comment: Wow, you just blew my mind with that. This query completed in 0.01 seconds and mine in 0.22. Any chance you can enlighten me as to why this speed difference? Is join just that much faster than subquery? Also Thank you for your quick reply and answer. I've literally been trying to improve this for days

Comment: Correlated subqueries like the ones you ahd are not best for performance. With good indexes, they are OK, but it's harder than with simple Joins. You'll probably need some composite indexes anyway, to improve further the efficiency.

Comment: I see. I tried to get the join working but I couldn't figure out how to properly join them. Thank you for showing me that example. I'll add the composite indexes. Thanks again!

Comment: No time now to investigate properly but an index on `(team_id, match_id, kills, total_gold)` seems good. Maybe combined with another on `(player_id, team_id, match_id)`